# New to Ruby, tried to build the simplest calculator, why is it not working?

Tags: ruby, calculator

```
class Calculator
  def firsti
    puts "Please type first number: "
  end

  def initialize(x)
    @x = gets.chomp
  end

  def opi
    puts "Please type operation: "
  end

  def initialize(y)
    @y = gets.chomp
  end

  def secondi
    puts "Please type second number: "
  end

  def initialize(z)
    @z = gets.chomp
  end

  if @y == '+'
    puts @x+@z
  elsif @y == '-'
    puts @x-@z
  elsif @y == '*'
    puts @x*@z
  elsif @y == '/'
    puts @x/@z
  else
    puts "Something went wrong. Please try again."
  end
end
```

Tried it with spaces, with or without ()-s, no error messages, I'm probably jut a noob. Any help would be appreciated. Initially tried with simple variables without a class, no result even though when I write just a simple

```
x = 2
y = +
z = 3
if y == '+'
  puts x+z
end
```

and it worked. Can't seem to understand what is the problem.

Comment: What's actually the problem? You mention that you have a problem, then don't say what it is. "Not working" isn't very descriptive.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Since I put the "else puts "Something is wong"" into the code, it only shows that one, previously there were no output at all. The calculator is not working in a sense that it is not calculating.

Comment: I don't know Ruby, but that means your conditions (such as `@y == '+'`) are giving false. Have you checked what the value of `@y` actually is? Does it have a newline on the end of it?

Comment: Please, show us the code where you are actually *calling* the calculator. Also, please, pretty please, format your code according to the Ruby Community Coding Style Guidelines, and use descriptive variable names. Also, why are you overwriting the `initialize` method twice?

Comment: Does not matter, with or without newline, same result. Tried to run the program in various environments that ask for the input differently, tried to input the +-s in many different ways, did not seem to have any affect.

Comment: @pajeszharcosdino Well, the probably is that the equality check is failing, which either means that's not how you compare strings in Ruby, or the variable doesn't contain what you think it does. You'll need to debug to figure it out if it's the latter.

Comment: Try mapping a function over the string that turns characters into their code. That should show if there's whitespace mixed in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "working version" of your code, which I have tried to make with minimal changes from your design:

```
class Calculator 

  def initialize 
    puts "Please type first number: " 
    @x = gets.chomp.to_i 
    puts "Please type operation: " 
    @y = gets.chomp 
    puts "Please type second number: " 
    @z = gets.chomp.to_i 
  end 


  def result 
    if @y == '+' 
      @x+@z 
    elsif @y == '-' 
      @x-@z 
    elsif @y == '*' 
      @x*@z 
    elsif @y == '/' 
      @x/@z 
    else 
      "Something went wrong. Please try again." 
    end 
  end 

end 

calculator = Calculator.new 
puts "Result is:" 
puts calculator.result
```

Your code has several issues preventing it from working as you expect:

- You have defined *multiple* `initialize` methods in a single class. This is not possible; all you're actually doing is *re-*defining the same method.
- Your code has no sense of flow control. You seem to be under the impression that "the code will all just run, from top to bottom". This is not how methods/classes work; you first *define* the methods/classes, and then *call* them. As you can see in my code, I am explicitly creating a `Calculator` object (`Calculator.new` - which constructs a new instance, calling the `initialize` method), and then calling the `result` method.
- On a similar note, you are performing a conditional check on the `@y` variable which **hasn't been defined** at this point in the code's execution! `@y` will be `nil` when your `if` statement executes; therefore, the logic falls through to the `else` statement.
- A more subtle point, but input from the `gets` command will always be a `String`. You need to call `to_i` to convert this into an `Integer`; otherwise, you'll get funny results like: `"2" + "5" == "25"`

Comment: Actually, thank you! Seeing your version of the code made something click in my brain and now I can finally understand the last x lessons I had no idea what they want me to do. Seeing it in action makes much more sense than written down. And also, thank you for the explanation, really helpful!